# Rationale choice of professions when assessing damages

Tags: torts-damages, mishneh-torah

Rambam Nezikin [Chovel uMazzik 2:11](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/1088909/jewish/Chovel-uMazzik-Chapter-Two.htm) states anent damages

> **If he caused him to lose a limb or cut off his hand**, he must pay him
> full compensation for his hand; this being "damages." In this
> instance, **we judge him as if he were a guard at a patch of squash.** We
> evaluate how much such a guard would earn each day and calculate the
> number of days he will be incapacitated. This is the amount the person
> who caused the injury must pay.
>
> Similarly, if a **person cut off a colleague's legs, we calculate a wage
> as if he were a door guard**. **If he blinded him, we calculate a wage as
> if he worked in a mill.** Similar principles apply in all analogous
> situations.

What's the Rambam's rationale selecting these specific professions, ie limb / hand loss wrt squash patch guard, leg loss wrt door guard and loss of vision wrt mill worker?

Comment: They are the types of jobs people with that specific disability could do.

Comment: @NT Blind working in a mill? FWIW it does not seem (at least to me) like intuitive / obvious jobs for the disabilities listed.

Comment: The mill one is likely a nod to Judges; the Philistines put blinded Samson to work pushing a millstone. (At least that's the literal reading; there's a midrash that reads "grinding" um, in a less-rated-G sense...)

Comment: Not "working in a mill" as in tending to customers. Being told "here is the wheel; we will feed grain into it, just keep pushing it around." In short, these made a lot of sense given the time and place.

Comment: כְּאִלּוּ הוּא טוֹחֵן בְּרֵחַיִם are the words of the Rambam; literally translated "as if he were grinding with a mill".

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok Thanks for the satisfying mill elucidation. Would you know: Why so specific for a patch of *squash* - not say just generic vegetable patch - for the hand / limbless?

Comment: Nowadays if he lost his legs he'd get paid as a software engineer or something

Comment: @Daniel Yaacov -  the expression is borrowed from [Mishnah Bovo Kamma 8 (2)](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Bava_Kamma.8.1?lang=he&lookup=%D7%A7%D6%B4%D7%A9%D6%BC%D7%81%D7%95%D6%BC%D7%90%D6%B4%D7%99%D7%9F&with=Commentary&lang2=he) שֶׁבֶת, רוֹאִין אוֹתוֹ כְּאִלוּ הוּא שׁוֹמֵר קִשּׁוּאִין. I guess that the expression of  שׁוֹמֵר קִשּׁוּאִין is not meant to be exclusive.